# Returning objects of different types based on template type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a class which holds variables of different types (let's say `std::string` and `keyword_map`) and which is supposed to have a `value()` function that returns either the string or the keyword_map value once it is called via template initialization `retval = object.value<std::string>()`. So far the function looks like this:

```
template <class T>
T value()
{
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
        return str_;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, keyword_map>::value) {
        return obj_;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compiling it throws me following error:
`error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'example_class::keyword_map' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (compiling source file ..\..\example_files\example_class.cpp)`

Is it possible I'll have to convert my return value to the template return type via `static_cast` or sth like that?

Comment: The type-checking is done at compile-time, and all paths through a function must be valid for the code to compile. You may want to consider *specialization* to handle the special cases.

Comment: Or perhaps better yet, use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or maybe even [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (if your compiler supports them, if not consider the Boost implementations of those instead).

Comment: Also note that `0` might not make sense all types. Do you have control over how this function will be called? Or will it be part of a library? How will you handle a case where `0` can't be converted to the type `T`?

Comment: `return 0;` was just an example way to explain my problem. I guess I'll go for an exception in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is true, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

e.g.

```
template <class T>
T value()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
        return str_;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, keyword_map>::value) {
        return obj_;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Before C++17, you can apply template specialization.

```
template <class T>
T value()
{
    return 0;
}

template <>
std::string value<std::string>()
{
    return str_;
}

template <>
keyword_map value<keyword_map>()
{
    return obj_;
}
```